# Extract hour from timestamp in 12 hour format with AM/PM indicator oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to extract hour from time-stamp column (oracle)  in 12 hour format with A.M/P.M indicator.

The column "subdate" has value  22-APR-20 04.18.40.000000000 PM

The Extract(HOUR from subdate) function returns

16

However, I want the value to be 4.00 PM

I have tried various options with the trunc and to_char functions but none of them gave the desired output.

Can you please help with this!

Thank you!

Comment: do you want 04:18 or 04:00 ?

Comment: And do you care if it is 04:00 or 04.00 or 4:00 or 4.00? (leading zero, and whether it is : or .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking about formats, you are not simply "extracting the hour" - you are really extracting a string.

```
TO_CHAR(subdate, 'hh.mi AM')
```

should do the trick.

**ADDED:** Based on comments. If you want : separator instead of . that is easy, just change it in the format mask. If you want to round down to the hour use trunc(subdate, 'hh') instead of subdate. If you need to drop the leading zero, you can wrap the entire expression in LTRIM(... , '0') or, as Alex Poole suggest, use the fm toggle like this:   'fmhh:fmmi AM'

Comment: this wont give 04:00 with minutes rounded to zero. However OP isn't clear whether thats what they want

Comment: Right - I didn't ask since you had already. Her input sample had :00:00.

Comment: The [FM modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF30003) will suppress the zero; `to_char(timestamp '2020-04-11 16:18:40', 'FMHH:MI AM')` gives `4:18 PM`.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Oh, great, I missed that (I did look, but where I looked the only use for FM had to do with removing BLANK padding). Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand, that mask would suppress the leading zero in the minute value as well, so 04:00 becomes `4:0 PM`, which is less desirable...so you'd need `'FMHH:FMMI AM'` to get `4:00 PM`. ("each subsequent occurrence toggles the effects of the modifier")

Comment: I'm not concerned about the minutes . I got the required output by TO_CHAR(subdate, 'HH AM'). Thank you all for the inputs!!

Comment: As Alex suggested, if you prefer to see the output as 1 PM instead of 01 PM, you can use   `TO_CHAR(subdate, 'FMHH AM')`